# Google colab: problems with pyvistaqt

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'm using colab for doing my projects. Right now I have a problem pyvistaqt, I'm not sure if that python package can use on colab, because I already installed but at the moment to run:

```py
plot_sensors_connectivity(epoch.info, con[:,:,0])
```

appear the following error:

> QtDeprecationError: `BackgroundPlotter` has moved to pyvistaqt.
> You can install this from PyPI with: `pip install pyvistaqt`
> See https://github.com/pyvista/pyvistaqt

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't display a pyqt widget within a jupyterlab environment, so anything you're trying to do right now using Qt should be avoided.  My guess is that `plot_sensors_connectivity` uses `pyvista.BackgroundPlotter`, and instead should just use `pyvista.Plotter`.